# How to add ROUND() in every cell of selection, but

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

cells are:

```
3.141516
=10/6
=rand()
or blank
etc...
```

result:

```
=ROUND(3.141516,1)
=ROUND(10/6,1)
=ROUND(RAND(),1)
```

and if blank - leave blank (not ROUND(,1) )

and I would like to choose range, and decimal by InputBox or something

*I found how to add ROUND() around formula, around Constants, with blank cells, with inputbox but all in a separate code, not together. I am not vba hero so I need help. thank you :)*

```
Sub RoundNum()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xNum As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Round Numbers"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xNum = Application.InputBox("Decimal", xTitleId, Type:=1)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Rng.Value, xNum)
Next
End Sub
Sub Makro1()
Dim Str As String
For Each cell In Selection
Str = cell.FormulaR1C1
If Mid(Str, 1, 1) = "=" Then Str = Mid(Str, 2)
cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(" & Str & ",1)"
Next cell
End Sub
```

---

on the end I did something like this:

```
Sub rRoundIt()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim AppCalc As Long
On Error Resume Next
With Application
    AppCalc = .Calculation
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
Set rng = Union(Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers), _
                Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers))
For Each rngArea In rng
    If Left(rngArea.Formula, 7) <> "=ROUND(" Then _
        rngArea.Formula = "=ROUND(" & Replace(rngArea.Formula, Chr(61), vbNullString) & ", 1)"
Next rngArea
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = AppCalc
End With
End Sub
```

thank you Jeeped :)

Comment: Show us your effort? SO isn't a free coding service

Comment: sorry I forgot put code here:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short sub takes advantage of the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) using both the xlCellTypeConstants and xlCellTypeFormulas options from [xlCellType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx). The .SpecialCells are further filtered by only garnering those constants or formulas that result in numbers with the **xlNumbers** option.

```
Sub roundIt()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .UsedRange.Cells
            Set rng = Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers), _
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers))
            For Each r In rng
                If Left(r.Formula, 7) <> "=ROUND(" Then _
                    r.Formula = "=ROUND(" & Replace(r.Formula, Chr(61), vbNullString) & ", 1)"
            Next r
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Ideally, you would want to offer some error control in case there are no formulas or constants within the worksheet's [.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) that represent numbers. If there are none to be found, then that .SpecialCells will return `nothing`.

By concentrating on only those cells which could posses a numerical value to apply a [ROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-C018C5D8-40FB-4053-90B1-B3E7F61A213C) to, you should shorten the iterations of your loop through the cells in the worksheet substantially.

Comment: It works fine :) but do I really need declare With Worksheets("Sheet1") ?

Comment: If you would prefer to work with a group of selected cells ([Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property) then have a look at the methods of referencing the Selection detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020?s=1|0.0000#28700020). You should have no trouble combining the two.

Comment: I added end code to original post, maybe it is not elegant but works :)