# Round off all cells of excel

Tags: excel

I have several decimal value cells in Excel which I want to round off to integers. I am also taking their sum. The problem is,

[image]

3.32+ 4.41 = 7.73
But if I round off each cell using simple formatting, I am getting 3+4=8. This problem does not arise when I  use =ROUND(cell, 0) in each cell.

Is there any easy way to round off all cells without manually correcting each cell as I have large dataset?

Comment: Formatting is not rounding. The values behind still have the commas. If you want rounded values, you will need to use the `round` function

Comment: Yes, my query is whether i can apply round function to all cells at once instead of applying it to cell one by one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add ROUND() in every cell of selection, but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159016/how-to-add-round-in-every-cell-of-selection-but)

Comment: If you're going to round off in your case, you'll get 7 while 8 is more accurate, what is your intended result there?

Comment: I want the result to be 7 as I have to report the table in integers only

Comment: So as well as round() there is roundup() and rounddown().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159016/how-to-add-round-in-every-cell-of-selection-but
I don't know to use VBA if it is that code. Sorry

Comment: Afaik, there's no way to use the round function on all your cells without VBA. Here's [how to get into the VBE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-insert-and-run-vba-code-in-excel/) and the code user11222393 gave you, you can then put into the ThisWorkbook section from the screenshots you'll see there.

Comment: Consider using `ROUND` in your formula.  For example `=SUM(ROUND(A1:B1,0))` would return `7` in the example you provide. This is not rounding all the cells, but without VBA, it might be useful.